# WPF работа с БД

Tags: c#, wpf

Где можно посмотреть как сделать приложение для работы с БД. Как сделать отображение таблицы в datagrid, занесения изменений, внесенных в datagrid, обратно в БД, каким способом  лучше взаимодействовать с БД и т.д. Из того что находил только обрывки с разными способами взаимодействия с БД.

Answer (score 1):

Скачать, а еще лучше купить книгу Троелсена Э., Шилдта Г. или Мак-Дональд Мэтью и почитать (имеются на русском языке). Возможно есть другие хорошие авторы, но я пока не встретил. А на форумах инета естественно будут только обрывки.

Ниже перечислены некоторые из них:

- Мак-Дональд Мэтью - Windows Presentation Foundation в .NET 4 с примерами на C# -2011
- Троелсен Э. - Язык программирования C# 2010 и платформа .NET 4 -2010
- Шилдт Г. Полное руководство С#4.0 -2010

Comment: Я как раз читаю эти книги но хотелось бы живого примера,я в этих книгах пока не нашел ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: Странно, я как раз все в них нашел. Что значит "живой пример"? Может надо просто не торопиться, и постепенно шаг за шагом... На сколько я помню, в этих книгах имеются очень даже понятные примеры. По крайней мере из всего перечисленного в Вашем вопросе, в них очень даже подробно описывается. Или вы хотите чтобы был готовый проект, в котором вы поправите несколько строчек и ваш проект готов? )))

Comment: Этот подойдет? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples